# Selected faces wont show in object mode but will show in edit mode

Tags: modeling

[image]

Title says it all, Selected faces wont show in object mode but will show in edit mode. I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and i have finally decided on getting help. I haven't changed anything in my blender.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Have you tried updating your graphics drivers? The latest versions of Blender also require slightly newer hardware than the older versions did. Can you post your hardware specs (specifically graphics)?

Comment: There was a bug in 2.91 https://developer.blender.org/T79811 , but in opposite way :) solved in latest experimental build, so check that if it relates.

Comment: My graphics is AMD Radeon HD 8670D